# Connection reset by peer when specifying TLS traffic in Istio

Tags: istio, consul, envoyproxy

I have a distributed database (Consul) that I want to run within Istio on Kubernetes. Communication between peers are encrypted and verified using mTLS. I am using a headless service to allow the peers to reach each other:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cluster
  namespace: consul
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  selector:
    app: consul
  ports:
  - name: tcp-server
    port: 8300
    targetPort: 8300
  - name: tcp-serflan
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8301
    targetPort: tcp-serflan
  - name: udp-serflan
    protocol: UDP
    port: 8301
    targetPort: udp-serflan
```

However, when I name the `tcp-server`  port on the headless service `tls-server` instead I see a load of connection reset errors:

```
2020/02/18 08:46:44 [INFO] serf: EventMemberUpdate: consul-0
2020/02/18 08:47:33 [ERR] agent: Coordinate update error: rpc error making call: stream closed
2020/02/18 08:47:38 [WARN]  raft: Heartbeat timeout from "10.0.3.146:8300" reached, starting election
2020/02/18 08:47:38 [INFO]  raft: Node at 10.0.2.114:8300 [Candidate] entering Candidate state in term 106
2020/02/18 08:47:38 [ERROR] raft: Failed to make RequestVote RPC to {Voter 54224806-ed63-0d1b-ae2c-9c1a09de43c4 10.0.3.146:8300}: EOF
2020/02/18 08:47:38 [ERROR] raft: Failed to make RequestVote RPC to {Voter 5b2e92ce-61d8-032e-dd94-c0d9eb1319a0 10.0.1.209:8300}: read tcp 10.0.2.114:40018->10.0.1.209:8300: read: connection reset by peer
2020/02/18 08:47:47 [WARN]  raft: Election timeout reached, restarting election
2020/02/18 08:47:47 [INFO]  raft: Node at 10.0.2.114:8300 [Candidate] entering Candidate state in term 107
2020/02/18 08:47:47 [ERROR] raft: Failed to make RequestVote RPC to {Voter 54224806-ed63-0d1b-ae2c-9c1a09de43c4 10.0.3.146:8300}: read tcp 10.0.2.114:40762->10.0.3.146:8300: read: connection reset by peer
2020/02/18 08:47:47 [ERROR] raft: Failed to make RequestVote RPC to {Voter 5b2e92ce-61d8-032e-dd94-c0d9eb1319a0 10.0.1.209:8300}: read tcp 10.0.2.114:40062->10.0.1.209:8300: read: connection reset by peer
```

How is Istio/Envoy treating TLS traffic that could be causing this issue? The traffic is TLS traffic (I am doing [this](https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/security-networking/certificates?utm_source=consul.io&utm_medium=docs)) so it seems it's necessary to pretend the traffic is TCP.

- Consul version: `1.6.2`
- Istio version: `1.4.4`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to expose a HTTPS port in an istio mesh secured with Mutual TLS

I ended up disabling TLS on my service, since istio encrypts the traffic anyways